# Locally connecting to RDS via ssh-tunnel using AWS SAM - ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, mariadb, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance running in AWS. I open an ssh-tunnel to this locally via the following command:

```
ssh -N -L 33336:<rds-host>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 <username>@<ip> -p <port> -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I also have an AWS Lambda using SAM that I run locally:

```
sam local start-api --env-vars env.json
```

Within this Lambda, I am trying to connect to this ssh-tunnelled RDS instance with `mariadb`:

```
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
  host: 'host.docker.internal',
  port: RDS_CONFIG.port || 33306,
  database: RDS_CONFIG.name || 'db_name',
  user: RDS_CONFIG.user || 'user',
  password: RDS_CONFIG.pass || 'pwd',
  timezone: 'UTC',
  dateStrings: true,
})
```

However, the connection to my database times out. I know to use `host.docker.internal`, but the problems persist. Here is the error:

```
"code":"ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT","name":"SqlError","text":"retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10001ms
```

I can, however, connect to this instance via ssh in DBeaver and query it. This means my ssh tunnel must be working.

How can I avoid this connection timeout in my locally running SAM app? Is there a good way to test this for issues?

I uninstalled and reinstalled both Docker and sam-cli to no avail.

Thanks all, this is driving me crazy!